# SwiftUI selected text background/foreground color (macOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui

Having this example, I cannot find a way to change the selected text background color:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct textselection: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .textSelection(.enabled)
            .background(.yellow)
            .frame(width:500, height:500)
    }
}

struct textselection_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        textselection()
    }
}
```

Looking at this image, I would like to see "World!" in green, for example:

[image]